# Toggle an icon of font awesome in the react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to the `react js.` I have an component where I show one icon that is ,

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

const Sorting = (props) => {
  return (
    <span className="d-inline-flex">
     <i className="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => props.sortData(props.type, 'ascending')}></i>
  )
}
export default Sorting;
```

Now, here What I want  to do is that ,

when there is a class of `down` then it is descending order and if user again click on the icon it will be `fa-angle-up` and the onclick of that will get called. So,

what I tried is

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

const Sorting = (props) => {
  const toggleAngle = props.toggleAngle ? <i className="fa fa-angle-down sort-icon" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => props.sortData(props.type, 'ascending', true)}></i> : <i className="fa fa-angle-up sort-icon" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => props.sortData(props.type, 'descending', false)}></i>
  return (
    <span className="d-inline-flex">
      {toggleAngle}
    </span>
  )
}
export default Sorting;


sortData = (key, order, toggleArrow) => {
    if (order === 'ascending') {
      this.setState({
        toggleAngle: toggleArrow
      })
      this.props.sortAscending(key);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        toggleAngle: toggleArrow
      })
      this.props.sortdescending(key);
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to do this ? 
 thanks.

Comment: The wordpress-like lines of infinite length finally introduced into the react, yea

Answer (score 1):

You should have different state for individual components.

// Parent Component

```
import React from "react";
import SortDataFunc from "./SortDataFunc";

class SortData extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { toggle: [true, true] };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(index) {
    this.setState(state => {
      return (state.toggle[index] = !state.toggle[index]);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SortDataFunc
          id="0"
          handleClick={this.handleClick}
          toggled={this.state.toggle[0]}
        />
        <SortDataFunc
          id="1"
          handleClick={this.handleClick}
          toggled={this.state.toggle[1]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SortData;
```

// Child Component

```
import React from "react";

const SortDataFunc = props => {
  const clickHandler = () => {
    props.handleClick(props.id);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <i
        className={`fa ${props.toggled ? "fa-angle-down" : "fa-angle-up"}`}
        aria-hidden="true"
        onClick={clickHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default SortDataFunc;
```

Comment: Hey could you please check what I have tried. I have added it in the answer

Comment: Here this is working for this but the only thing is that I have this icon on 5 headers. so, I have did this for one then other five are also getting toggled.

Answer (score 0):

`Sorting` component has own state `sort`.

```js
class Sorting extends React.Componet {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {sort:'ascending'}
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  clickHandler(){
    let sort = this.state.sort === 'ascending' ? 'descending' : 'ascending';
    this.setState({
      sort
    })
    this.props.sortData(this.props.type, sort);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <span className="d-inline-flex">
       <i className={`fa fa-angle-${this.state.sort === 'ascending' ? 'down' : 'up'}`} aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.clickHandler}></i>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey I have done the same way, the only thing is that I have  <Sorting sortData={this.sortData} iconDirection={this.state.iconDirection} />  for the 5 times as this is for each column. So that is the problem that I am facing.

Comment: @ganesh I edited. Although I wrote 5 times for understanding, you can use `map`.

Comment: Actually index is the thing that I have to use

Comment: @ganesh Hmm.. No, I think it's better to have `Sorting Components` in their own state.

Comment: actually I did not get .. as I have only one sorting component for all.

Comment: Hey and one more thing is that the parameter should also get change. when user click on the descending arrow, the parameter should be a descending order arroe